# Ionic GET request to backend protected by an htpasswd

Tags: javascript, api, nginx, ionic-framework, .htpasswd

I need to get data from my backend with a get request but the backend is protected by an htpasswd.
So my backend return `Unauthorized` what is the best way to send my credential to the backend and how to store them safely ?

```
 this.http.get("http://backend.com/api/data", {}).subscribe(data => {
      this.dataService.createDatabase(data);
 });
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Hello,

Have you tried to add:

    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password));
    }                      ???        Also you can use:

$.ajax
({
  type: "GET",
  url: "index1.php",
  dataType: 'json',
  headers: {
    "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa(USERNAME + ":" + PASSWORD)
  },
  data: '{ "comment" }',
  success: function (){
    alert('Thanks for your comment!'); 
  }
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was :

```
    var base64Auth = btoa("USER:PASSWORD");
    var reqHeader = new HttpHeaders();
    reqHeader = reqHeader.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' + base64Auth);

    this.http.get("http://engitechs.a3web.fr/api/data", { headers: reqHeader }).subscribe(data => {
      this.dataService.createDatabase(data);
    });
```

And some CORS configuration in my nginx conf to authorize OPTIONS request to work without htpasswd